# Adobe Air Application

Tags: air, ms-word, adobe

Can anyone direct me to an Adobe Air tutorial or reference for building an Air application that lets the user view a Microsoft Word document?

In other words, can I read a Word document from an Adobe Air Application?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: To clarify the clarification, in case you don't know how:  When you look at your past questions you'll see a grey tick mark by each of the answers users have submitted.  Find the one which best answers the question and click on that tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the contents of the Word document in your app, you can use

```
<input  type="file" />
```

then get the data from that.